# How to set list to tuple within dictionary for jks

Tags: python

I am using [pyjks](https://pypi.org/project/pyjks/) with Python 2.7 as follows:

```
import jks

ks = jks.KeyStore.load('xxxx.jceks', 'xxxxx')
for alias, sk in ks.secret_keys.items():
    print("Secret key: %s" % sk.alias)
    print("  Algorithm: %s" % sk.algorithm)
    print("  Key size: %d bits" % sk.key_size)
    print("  Key: %s" % "".join("{:02x}".format(b) for b in bytearray(sk.key)))
    print(sk.key)
```

which gives:

```
Secret key: xxxxxxx
  Algorithm: AES
  Key size: 128 bits
  Key: xxxx
someweirdcharacters
Secret key: xxxxxxx
  Algorithm: AES
  Key size: 128 bits
  Key: yyyy
 someotherweirdcharacters
```

which is fine, but I am very rusty at Python, so was wondering, what is the best way of putting `someweirdcharacters` and `someotherweirdcharacters` into a list?

I don't know how to access `sk.key` from `ks.secret_keys.items()` except as in the loop above, but is seems there should be a simpler way.

Comment: Are you asking for something other than `list(sk.key)`?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I am not sure. Will that put all the keys in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like below?

```
 import jks

arr = []
ks = jks.KeyStore.load('xxxx.jceks', 'xxxxx')
for alias, sk in ks.secret_keys.items():
    print("Secret key: %s" % sk.alias)
    print("  Algorithm: %s" % sk.algorithm)
    print("  Key size: %d bits" % sk.key_size)
    print("  Key: %s" % "".join("{:02x}".format(b) for b in bytearray(sk.key)))
    arr.append(sk.key)
 print(arr)
```

Comment: That'll do. So obvious now. Thanks!